# Syntax error insert in Apache Beam code

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am writing Apache beam code for testing. Please refer the code below. I created sample SimpleFunction and apply code and trying to compile.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Test Log");

        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        //options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
        options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("hdfs://path/to/*.gz"))
            // withCompression can be omitted - by default compression is detected from the filename.
            .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
            .apply(MapElements
                // uses imports from TypeDescriptors
                .via(
                    new SimpleFunction <ReadableFile, KV<String,String>>() {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7867677L;

                        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                        public KV<String,String> createKV(ReadableFile f) {
                            String temp = null;
                            try{
                            temp = f.readFullyAsUTF8String();
                            }catch(IOException e){

                            }
                            return KV.of(f.getMetadata().resourceId().toString(), temp);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String apply(ReadableFile element, KV<String, String> input) {
                            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                            return str.toString();
                        }
                    }

            ))
            .apply(FileIO.write());
        p.run();
    }
```

but compiler is throwing `syntax error at public String apply(ReadableFile`

I tried but not successful to fix this, Could someone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleFunction<InputT, OutputT>` takes a value of `InputT` and returns the value of `OutputT`. The signature of `apply` in this case is `OutputT apply(InputT input);`, see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/144bffd4024decbc586bf16efe05caeda9427d77/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/SimpleFunction.java#L64).

In your case for your types the `SimpleFunction` will have to look like this:

```
new SimpleFunction <ReadableFile, KV<String,String>>() {
   ...
   @Override
   public KV<String,String> apply(ReadableFile input) {
      ...
   }
}
```

For example see how it is used [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/83419241ad72fa8d1e4d214ff8b728b9bd3163af/sdks/java/extensions/jackson/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/jackson/ParseJsons.java#L62).

In your case you need more logic around `readMatches()`, see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/82c32deb38b861ad7ac7baae90bcb730230b1904/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.java#L608) for example how it is applied to parse Avros, and [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0cbcf4ad1db7d820c5476d636f3a3d69062021a5/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/ReadAllViaFileBasedSource.java#L60) is the implementation details of the `PTransform` from that code.

Comment: Ok got it. 1.) But, I didn't get "more logic around readMatches()," how to do this? 2.) Also, I need to parse a JSON file as well and read it and Stream it. Is there sample to read JSON and Stream?

Comment: I have another question here on the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516636/apache-beam-reading-json-and-stream?noredirect=1#comment88048858_50516636