# Apache Beam - Reading JSON and Stream

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am writing Apache beam code, where I have to read a JSON file which has placed in the project folder, and read the data and Stream it.

This is the sample code to read JSON. Is this correct way of doing it?

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<String> lines = p.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from("/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace/beam-prototype/test.json"));
System.out.println("lines: " + lines);
```

or I should use,

```
p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace/beam-prototype/test.json"))
```

I just need to read the below json file. Read the complete `testdata` from this file and then Stream it.

```
{
“testdata":{
“siteOwner”:”xxx”,
“siteInfo”:{
“siteID”:”id_member",
"siteplatform”:”web”,
"siteType”:”soap”,
"siteURL”:”www”,
}
}
}
```

The above code is not reading the json file, it is printing like

```
lines: ReadMyFile/Read.out [PCollection]
```

, could you please guide me with sample reference?

Comment: You probably need to call some sort of `collect()` method on the `PCollection`.

Comment: Is my code is correct? Is there any sample for collect()?

Answer (score 1):

> This is the sample code to read JSON. Is this correct way of doing it?

To quickly answer your question, yes. Your sample code is the correct way to read a file containing JSON, where each line of the file contains a single JSON element. The `TextIO` input transform reads a file line by line, so if a single JSON element spans multiple lines, then it will not be parseable.

The second code sample has the same effect.

> The above code is not reading the json file, it is printing like

The printed result is expected. The variable `lines` does not actually contain the JSON strings in the file. `lines` is a `PCollection` of `String`s; it simply represents the state of the pipeline after a transform is applied. Accessing elements in the pipeline can be done by applying subsequent transforms. The actual JSON string can be access in the implementation of a transform.

Comment: Ok thanks Andrew. Could you also advise me how to Stream such data using Apache beam API?